# IndexOutOfBounds, but why?

Tags: java, android, indexing

I'm writing an app's code and when I enter only 2 numbers I get indexoutofbounds Length=2 Index=2. Why is this/how can I circumvent it?
Here is my code:

```
        Arrays.sort(newNums);
        double median = 0;
        if(newNums.length%2!=0){
            median = (double) newNums[newNums.length/2];
        }else if(newNums.length%2==0){
            median = ( (double) newNums[newNums.length/2 + 1] + (double) newNums[newNums.length/2-1] )/2;
        }else{

        }
        String medianString = Double.toString(median);
        showDialog(medianString, type,"Median:");
```

Comment: array index start from 0

Comment: Basic Java (and most languages).  Indices are zero based.  The first item has an index of zero, the second index is one through to index=length-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newNums.length/2 + 1` == `2` for `newNums.lenght` == `2`

You probably don't want `+ 1` there to sum two values on the indexes next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes in Java start from 0. This expression `newNums[newNums.length/2 + 1]` will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the size of the array is 2.

Answer (score 0):

The erros is:

`median = ( (double) newNums[newNums.length/2 + 1] + (double) newNums[newNums.length/2-1] )/2;`

When `newNums.length == 2`, this will result in `IndexOutOfBoundError`.

Also, the median of a even length array is the average of two **consecutive** middle elements, but your code gives the average of `middle + 1` and `middle - 1` elements.

Instead, use this:

`median = ( (double) newNums[newNums.length/2] + (double) newNums[newNums.length/2-1] )/2;`